# MUI datatable, Hide search Icon but still show the search bar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

Im working with MUI-datatable and my table options contain

```
options:{
search: false,
searchOpen: true,
...
}
```

according to the docs "search:false" should only hide the icon to toggle the search bar, and searchOpen, should show the search bar by default.

But at the moment it removes the search bar AND icon.

Here is a sandbox where I have search set to disabled which only disables the icon (but actually want to set to false)

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-haslett-40jlf?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Adding theme and overriding it by:

```
createMuiTheme({
overrides: {
MUIDataTableToolbar: {
            iconActive: {
                display: 'none',
            },
        },
},
})
```

Where iconActive is the Search Button